# Will this particular cronjob work?

Tags: unix, cron

this is my cronjob, it should run from April-July and from October-January, every morning at exactly 8.00 and only from Monday to Friday.

```
0 8 * 1,4-7,10-12 1-5
```

I tried this parser http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php but it tells me "Cannot be parsed" even though this one

```
0 8 * 1,4-7,8-9 1-5
```

which is basically the same logic works...

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Try other websites: http://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_1,4-7,10-12_1-5

Comment: Yes, this should work as you expect.
The site you linked appears to be buggy.

Comment: thank you two for your help!